How to build a CMake library and include its header files with a namespace?
I have a CMake project with a folder structure like this:
my repo here
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── conanfile.py
├── include
│   └── my_algorithm.h
├── src
│   └── my_algorithm.cpp
└── test_package
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── conanfile.py
    └── src
        └── example.cpp

In my test_package/src/example.cpp, I have an example.cpp file like this
#include "my_algorithm.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    algorithm();
}

How can I make CMake to build my project so that my include/algorithm.h will be imported as foundation/algorithm.h for examples by others who consume my library?
My current CMakeLists.txt is like this
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(my_foundation CXX)

add_library(my_foundation src/algorithm.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_foundation PUBLIC include)

set_target_properties(my_foundation PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "include/algorithm.h")
install(TARGETS my_foundation)

I have followed two approaches to create a "namespace" for my library.
Approach 1 - Add Folder in my include directory
I changed the folder structure of the repo
+ CMakeLists.txt
+ include
  + my_foundation
    + my_algorithm.h

And the CMakeLists.txt is changed to
add_library(my_foundation src/my_algorithm.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_foundation PUBLIC include)

set_target_properties(my_foundation PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "include/my_foundation/my_algorithm.h")

But when I test importing my library in my external usage,
I still have to import my header as my_algorithm.h instead of my_foundation/my_algorithm.h
#include "my_foundation/my_algorithm.h" # Not working


//#include "my_algorithm.h" // Working

My trial can be found here repo
Approach 2 - Only add "namespace" for External usage
My preferred way repo.
I have changed the CMakeLists.txt file
add_library(my_foundation src/my_algorithm.cpp)
- #target_include_directories(my_foundation PUBLIC include)
+ target_include_directories(my_foundation PRIVATE include/my_foundation include)
+ target_include_directories(my_foundation INTERFACE include)

Still, I get the same result as Approach 1, I can only import my header as my_algorithm.h instead of my_foundation/my_algorithm.h
Edit
My test_package/CMakeLists.txt look
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(PackageTest CXX)
find_package(my_foundation CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example my_foundation::my_foundation)

I am using conan2 to install cpp packages and test my cpp package..
The commands I create the cpp library are
conan install .
cmake --preset conan-release
cmake --build --preset conan-release


This "namespace" is nothing but a directory. If you want a foundation directory to be there, you only need to create it.
Change your directory structure to the following layout (only relevant files shown below):
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── include
    └── foundation
        └── algorithm.h

In your CMakeLists.txt you need not change anything. The two lines
add_library(algorithm ...)
target_include_directories(algorithm PUBLIC include)

... will add include to the include directory search path. Thus, everybody will have to #include "foundation/algorithm.h" to include the respective file.
If you want to change it only for external usage, you could do
add_library(algorithm ...)
target_include_directories(algorithm PRIVATE include/foundation)
target_include_directories(algorithm INTERFACE include)

Although I would just use the foundation prefix internally as well and be done with it.
In your specific case, I'd definitely do so only to avoid confusion between your foundation/algorithm.h and the standard library's algorithm header.
To preserve the header file with its subdirectories after installation, you would also need to pass it to the install() command as described in CMake docs on install:
install(TARGETS my_foundation
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/include/foundation
)


Hi Friedrich. I found myself unable to replicate. In approach-1, "put header inside folder:, I found I still have to import my foundation/algorithm.h file as algorithm.h in my consumer.

https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/cpp-naming-example/tree/approach-1

I prefer the second way, keeping my current folder structure and the consumer has to import my header with namespace, say "my_foundation/my_algorithm.h", but I found myself unable to replicate it as well... Same as approach 1, I can only import the header file without "namespace".

https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/cpp-naming-example/tree/approach-2-external

Would you mind taking a look?? I have created two branches to test your suggestion on github. @friedrich

Sorry I made it private. It is public now @ friedrich

I have made the repo public and posted my test_package/CMakeLists.txt's content here. As I am using theinstall() directives instead of add_executable() in CMakeLists.txt, would you mind showing how to achieve it too???

I think the install command matters. When I run cmake --build --preset conan-release I cannot see the include folder in the build directory. I cannot see the include directory too when I cd into the directory when conan create . creates.

Errors like the following comes out....
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
Imported target "my_foundation::my_foundation" includes non-existent path
"/Users/user/.conan2/p/b/my_fo0fd7108876240/p/include"

in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:


The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.


An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.


The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
provide.



I have created a new branch
https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/cpp-namespace-example/tree/conan-install
demonstrating what I mean

@whyuenacccc I made yet another edit to show how the install() command would need to be used. KIndly take a look.

I made the change but found it works with neither the cmake --build --preset conan-release [1] nor conan create . [2]. [1] In build/release folder I found no include folder`.... [2] just reaffirm it... @Friedrich

@whyuenacccc this is becoming an exercise in debugging well beyond the scope of your original question.

Finally the working solution
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── conanfile.py
├── include
│   └── my_algorithm.h
├── src
│   └── my_algorithm.cpp
└── test_package
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── conanfile.py
    └── src
        └── example.cpp

and my CMakeLists.txt file
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(my_foundation CXX)

add_library(my_foundation src/my_algorithm.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_foundation PUBLIC include)

set_target_properties(my_foundation PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "include/my_algorithm.h")
install(TARGETS my_foundation PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/my_foundation)

The header files are not in the build/Release folder, but it's ok.
